# Highchart drilldown subtitle change

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How can I change the subtitle and not the title?

```
series: {
              cursor: 'pointer',
              point: {
                events: {
                 click: function() {//alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);

                     var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                     if (drilldown) { // drill down

                         this.series.chart.setTitle({
                             text: drilldown.name 
                         });                     

                     } else { // restore

                     }
                 }
                }
              }
           }
        },
```

will it be like:

```
this.series.chart.setSubTitle({
                                 text: 'vlabla'
                          });
```

I tried it with the above it doesn't work

Please help anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [drilldown](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) and [drillup](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drillup) events of chart that could be used to call [`chart.setTitle()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle). To set only subtitle and leave a title unchanged you could set title options object to null:

```
      chart.setTitle(null, {
        text: "after drilldown subtitle" //subtitle options
      });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/axdcLmfx/